# Changing div's order with CSS with dynamic height, text vertical align middle

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

Here's my HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox"><img 1></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox"><img 2></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox"><img 3></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox"><img 4></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 4</div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

The expected result in desktop is:

```
_____________________
|  img 1  |  txt 1  |
_____________________
|  txt 2 |   img2   |
_____________________
|  img 3  |  txt 3  |
_____________________
|  txt 4  |  img 4  |
_____________________
```

each block width:50%, images width:100% to the box, auto height;
text in the middle of the box, like display:table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;

and expected result on mobile is:

```
___________
|  img 1  |
___________
|  txt 1  |
___________ 
|  img 2  |
___________
|  txt 2  |
___________ 
|  img 3  |
___________
|  txt 3  |
___________ 
|  img 4  |
___________
|  txt 4  |
___________
```

everything is  width:100% to the page

If I set display:flex to li, I can change the order of even row's,
however, I don't find the way to make the text box 100% height, text align center.
https://jsfiddle.net/wesleywai/phcgmopo/10/

If I use display:table to lia nd display:table-cell to div, I can make it 100% height like a native table cell but I don't find the way to change the order:
https://jsfiddle.net/wesleywai/amm5mmvm/2/

I've also tried direction: rtl; and direction: ltr; and it doesn't seem to be working on my case.

Please help.

Comment: `I don't find the way to make the text box 100% height`. Which textbox? I can't see where it is in the code.

Comment: He meant the div (box) that contains the text :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `height: 100%` on the `div` rule

You can drop the `vertical-align:middle;` too since it has no effect in this case, and if you want to vertical center the text, I added a new rule

```
.txtBox {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
ul{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
div{
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  background:#fcc;
}
.txtBox {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;     /*  horizontal - when flex row */
  align-items: center;         /*  vertical   - when flex row */
}
li:nth-child(even) .imgBox{
  order:2;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 68px) {
  li{
    display:block;
  }
  div{
    width:100%
   }
  .txtBox{
    padding:20px;
    width:calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/132419/pexels-photo-132419.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/103573/pexels-photo-103573.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/132474/pexels-photo-132474.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 4
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, the div is now auto height.  but is there anyway to make the text vertical-align:middle like in table cell?

Comment: Thanks very much ,  I think this is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

My solution with display table:

```css
ul{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
div{
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:#fcc;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  direction: rtl;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  li{
    display:block;
  }
  div{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
   }
  .txtBox{
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/132419/pexels-photo-132419.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/103573/pexels-photo-103573.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/132474/pexels-photo-132474.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb'>
    </div>
    <div class="txtBox">
      FLOWER 4
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was a slick variant for older browsers, +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

For changing the order of every second `<li>` you can use CSS Flexbox's `flex-direction: row-reverse` property that will change the order of the `<li>` elements.

Use **`align-self: stretch`** property on **`txtBox`**, to make it 100% height.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Changing the order for every 'even' element */
li.list:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  li.list {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  li.list:nth-child(even) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.txtBox {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="http://placehold.it/60/60"></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="http://placehold.it/60/60"></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="http://placehold.it/60/60"></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="http://placehold.it/60/60"></div>
    <div class="txtBox">text 4</div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Learn more about [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm ... the OP already use flexbox....?, the question was the size of the text box, so if you read the question properly you will see that

Comment: @LGSon Oh! my bad, but if we use `align-self: stretch` property on `txtBox` we can make the height of txtBox 100% too. @Wesleywai Please have a look and let me know if you still need some help.

Comment: By dropping `height: 100%` it automatically adjust, so no need with any extra properties

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind wrapping the content of the `txtBox` in another DIV, you can set that div's content with

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

To make sure it's centered vertically.

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gfd0ta98/

Comment: It is much simpler ... check my answer

Comment: css always gives you multiple solutions :)